One of three of my shapefiles not loading into NetLogo gis:extension
I have created three shapefiles of buildings from OSM via QGIS and exported them to the same folder. Two of the files open fine into Netlogo using the gis extension and gis:load-dataset but the third (made at the same time and covering the same canvas) will not load. I get the message :
Extension exception: null<br>
error while observer running GIS:LOAD-DATASET<br>
  called by procedure DRAW_BUILDINGS_YES<br>
  called by procedure SETUP<br>
  called by Button 'Setup'<br>
org.nlogo.nvm.WrappedExtensionException: Extension exception: null
 at org.nlogo.prim._externreport.report(_externreport.java:35)
 at org.nlogo.prim._asm_proceduredraw_buildings_yes_setobservervariable_0.perform() ...

It opens fine into GAMA (another ABM software) so the file seems to have been formed ok and not corrupted.
This third file is quite a lot larger than the first two (the .dbf is 713 MB whilst the first two have 31 MB and 7 MB). Could that be the problem?

The best next step is to file an error-ticket at NetLogo GIS developers. Did you file it, before posting here?

I didn't - I'll do that now
